# 2sxc template error when under Host file system

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Im using the Tiles app from 2sxc.org. When the Razor template location is selected as Host File System it throws the following error

[image]

**Web.Config** 
*under /Portals/0/2sxc folder where razor template works*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor">
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="ToSic.SexyContent.Razor.SexyContentWebPage">
      <namespaces>
        <!--<add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="WebMatrix.Data" />-->
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

**Web.Config Portal** 
*under /Portals/ folder *

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>  
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc"/>
    <pages pageBaseType="DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc.Framework.DnnWebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc.Helpers"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

**Web.Config Host** 
There is no web.config file under /Portals/_default/2sxc

**Platform and 2sxc version:**
DNN Evoq Content 08.04.02 (5) *(both local and Azure based installation exhibit same errors)*
2sxc 8.5.4

Comment: This is strange - it looks like the @Edit-object is missing. Please provide more details as to: your dnn-version, your 2sxc-version and please copy-paste the web.config from your portals/_default (the host-area) and the portals/xx (your portal where it works)

Comment: Thats what I thought, however other 2sxc razor based template throw errors as well if the template location is changed to Host.

Comment: Token based templates work fine even if their location is changed to host.

I'm using DNN Evoq Content 08.04.02 (5) (both local and Azure based installation exhibit same errors), 2sxc 8.5.4.

Will post both web.config of host and portal tomorrow. If you can test at your end changing the Razor based template location to host on DNN Evoq perhaps you'll know more.

Comment: if i copy the web.config file from \Portals\0\2sxc to \Portals\_default\2sxc the module starts working.

But how come the web.config is present under \Portals\0\2sxc and not under the Host \Portals\_default\2sxc

Comment: I'm not sure if the web.config is missing by default, or if it's something specific to your install. we'll check - and we created an issue https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/973